# How to Call Ajax With Same Div Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am calling ajax with below code in my index.php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#counting").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://example.com/update.php',
                data: {url: '<?=$url?>'},
                success: function(data) {
                   // alert(data);
                    //$("p").text(data);

                }
            });
   });
});
</script>
```

It's working perfectly, but the issue is
I have div called counting multiple times on the page.
example

```
 <div id="counting">
<a href="example.com">example</a>
</div>

 <div id="counting">
<a href="example.com">example</a>
</div>
```

Issue - Ajax call only works with first div, not below divs.
How to make it work with all divs with id counting

Comment: "An id can't and must not be the same across all your HTML"

Comment: Thanks, I used class instead of ID and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Id attributes are supposed to be unique. You're only ever going to get the first div called because once the DOM sees that, it's met it's requirement and doesn't search further. I suggest you give you divs unique ids and then use a class that is the same for all of them.

```
 <div id="div1" class="counting_class">
<a href="example.com">example</a>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="counting_class">
<a href="example.com">example</a>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery would look something like this:

```
$(".counting_class").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
//then call ajax based on the individual ID
}
```